# Android: AWS Amplify User State is not getting update

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I have just started learning AWS Amplify and I am integrating it to my android project to authenticate users. I have successfully logged-in but `UserState` is still `SIGNED_OUT`.

```kotlin
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(userName, password, null, callback)
```

**Callback Code snippet**

```kotlin
fun fetchAuthenticationCallBack(): Callback<SignInResult> {
    return object : Callback<SignInResult> {
        override fun onResult(result: SignInResult?) {
            when (result?.signInState) {
                SignInState.DONE -> {
                    // AWSMobileClient.getInstance().confirmSignIn()
                    Log.d(TAG, "LOGIN SUCCESS ${AWSMobileClient.getInstance().tokens.accessToken}")
                }

                SignInState.NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "NEW PASSWORD CHALLENGE")
                }

                else -> {
                    // Unsupported sign-in confirmation:
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onError(e: java.lang.Exception?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the accessToken but it gives me Exception

```
Token does not support retrieving while user is SIGN_OUT
```

Is there anything that I am missing in the authentication part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone will face this issue in the future.

Kindly check your `awsconfiguration.json` file there is something went wrong. In my case `CognitoIdentity` credentials were wrong. I have just fixed the `awsconfiguration.json` file everything is working as expected

Comment: Could you specifically mention what was wrong?
json settings? Configuration in the AWS console?

Comment: There might be a wrong pool id, region, identity id, etc. You will have to check your pool secrets in aws console and match with your json file